# Exception in thread "main" NullPointerException

Tags: java

No entiendo el por que de este este error, si que es cierto que debes inicializar el array pero aun asi me sigue saltando el mismo error.

```
class Kata  
{

double contador[];

public double[] averages(int[] numbers) {


for(int i=0;i<numbers.length;i++) {
contador[i]=(double) ((numbers[i]+numbers[i+1])/2);
    System.out.println(contador[i]);
}
return new double[0];
}
}
```

Aqui esta el main

```
public class problema {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Kata obj = new Kata();  
    System.out.println(obj.averages(new int[]{ 2, 2, 2, 2, 2 }));
}

}
```

El reporte

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at entrenamiento.Kata.averages(codewars.java:60)
at entrenamiento.problema.main(codewars.java:11)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que `contador` no es inicializado en ningún momento. Tendrías entonces que calcular el tamaño de `numbers` para inicializar `contador` con ese tamaño, algo así:

```
    int nLength=numbers.length;
    this.contador= new double[nLength];
```

Luego esta parte del código:

```
contador[i]=(double) ((numbers[i]+numbers[i+1])/2);
```

Te dará un *`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`*, porque al aumentar el índice a uno dentro del bucle: `numbers[i+1]`, llega un momento en que te sales de los límites del mismo índice.

Escrito así el método funcionaría:

```
public double[] averages(int[] numbers) {
    int nLength=numbers.length;
    contador= new double[nLength];
    for(int i=0;i<nLength;i++) {
        contador[i]=(double) ((numbers[i])/2);
        System.out.println(contador[i]);
    }
    return contador;
}
```

**Salida:**

```
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
```

En cuanto a esta línea `contador[i]=(double) ((numbers[i]+numbers[i+1])/2);`, debes aclararte sobre qué es lo que quieres calcular ahí realmente.

Otra cosa extraña es que retornes un `new double[0];` desde tu método.

Comment: Muchas gracias , ahora si que funciona, respecto al valor de retorno `new double[0]` es por que esta clase que estoy haciendo para resolver un problema de la web 'codewars' y el metodo ya te viene con ese return.